# Does fermentation temperature have to be consistent as well as within the high and low markers?

Tags: fermentation, yeast, fermentation-temperature

I don't have a fermentation fridge so I have to put my fermenter in the best spot to get the correct temperature; and keep an eye on it and move it or heat/cool it if necessary. My last brew I used Safale US-05 and I was aiming for a starting temperature of 16°C letting it rise to around 22°C after 3 days and holding it around 20/22 °C to the end, which I understand is a good profile for the yeast.

However to cut a long story short and my "cold" room was too cold and my "warm" room was too warm and the beer ended up sort of swinging from 12°C to 22°C a number of times, but this is still within the Fermentis recommendations, in fact it was mostly between 15 and 22 which is what they say it should be **ideally**.

`FERMENTATION TEMPERATURE: 12-25°C (53.6-77°F) ideally 15-22°C (59-71.6°F)`

My question is **does it have to be a consistent temperature** as well as being between 12°C and 22°C ... and if it does **what negative effects would a fluctuation in temperature cause**?

I think there were probably 3-5 signifignant cyles of 12/15 °C to 20/22 °C and back again

**US05 PDF** - http://www.fermentis.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Safale-US-05-en.pdf

**EDIT** it just occurred to mention my gravity readings, which surprised me a bit but not sure. The fermentation went from 1058 to 1012 in 5 days

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"*does it have to be a consistent temperature*" - IMHO, no.

"*what negative effects would a fluctuation in temperature cause*" - very few unless the temperature was mainly tending to the high end of the range. Then it might give a more fruity flavour to the brew - which is not a bad thing but may not be what one wants. If the temperature dips too low for a longer time then the beer may cool and will only warm slowly. The lower temperature may produce a "cleaner/crisper" beer but will usually inhibit the yeast and so will require longer to ferment. Its a case of "swings and roundabouts". While the mentioned 3 thermal cycles between 12 and 22 may have some effect I doubt it would seriously detract from an otherwise fine brew. And I also doubt it will it turn an otherwise bad brew into a good one!

Comment: thanks - I should have put in my question ( doing it now ) that the beer also fermented much faster than I had expected - went from 1058 to 1012 in 5 days; now sure whether that's OK or an indicator of anything else

Comment: The quoted drop in SG over a period of 5 days is not unreasonable. I personally would not bottle or transfer the beer before 14 days in the fermentation vessel - whatever the SG. Then I would bottle it - whatever I thought it initially tasted like. From the comments above, I doubt there is anything wrong with the brew.

Comment: ok that's cool I might do that - it fermented so fast I never got to dry hop it